# Regex to replace some instances of a word but not others

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to figure out a regular expression to replace the word contained in some strings from "Name1" to "N1", in RUBY:

```
Name1_Instance_1 --> N1_Instance_1
Name1_Instance_2 --> N1_Instance_2
```

But not if the string contains a .xml at the end:

```
Name1.xml
Name1_Instance.xml
```

I've tried this:

```
Name1[\w_]*[^.xml]
```

But it doesn't exclude this case

`Name1_Instance.xml`

Comment: Why does it have to be a regular expression? An customer requirement, or an arbitrary decision?

Comment: I needed a smart search replace, that would not touch file references, because it would screw up stuff in a bunch of xml files

Comment: That doesn't say why it has to be a regex though. They can become maintenance nightmares, and many people are enamored with using them for the wrong reasons. They are powerful, but that can come at a cost so go there carefully. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
Name(?=\d+)(?!\w*\.xml)
```

Here I used a lookahead assertion (`(?=\d+)`) to see if one or more digits follows Name, and then I used a negative lookahead assertion (`(?!\w*\.xml)`) to exclude any item that ends in `.xml`. Lookahead assertions of any variety do not consume any of the string and do not return any part of the lookahead assertion in the result.

In Ruby, you can do this:

```
t = """Name1_Instance_1    
.. .. .. .. Name1_Instance_2    
.. .. .. .. Name1.xml    
.. .. .. .. Name1_Instance.xml""".gsub /Name(?=\d+)(?!\w*\.xml)/, 'N'

print t
N1_Instance_1   
.. .. .. N1_Instance_2   
.. .. .. Name1.xml   
.. .. .. Name1_Instance.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Name1\w*(?!\.xml)
```

`?!` is the [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: I replaced `[\w_]` with `\w`, because `\w` already contains the underscore.

Comment: Is the parenthesis necessary for the look ahead? I do not wish to select it.

Comment: It is neccessary, and it will not get selected because it is a lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negative lookahead that looks like:

```
Name1[\w]*(?!\.xml)
```